# Choosing how the repeating indices in a sparse matrix are aggregated

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

When we construct a scipy sparse matrices (such as `coo_matrix`, `csc_matrix` or `csr_matrix`) from `(data, (row_ind, col_ind))`, by default the entries at duplicate `(row_ind, col_ind)` are summed together. For example:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

row_ind  = [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
col_ind  = [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1]
data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

coo_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind))).todense()

matrix([[3, 2, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]])
```

Is there a way to specify another operation like `min`, `max`, `mean` instead of the `sum`? Also, it would be useful to have a method like `sum_duplicates()` for these operations too.

Comment: There's nothing built in.  While it might be possible to make a change in the `coo` to `csr` conversion method, I think the simplest thing is to deal with the duplicates yourself, before constructing the `coo`.  In your example, the duplicates aren't summed in the 'raw' `coo` matrix.  They are summed by `todense` (via a `tocsr` conversion).

Comment: Hi @Andreas K. , Have you found a solution other than the one suggested in the comments ?